# Searching Related Tables in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, relates, search

The point of this project is to find the deceased's name in a cemetery so the public can find them easily. I have uploaded a shapefile of cemetery lots and a table of lot occupants (so I did a 1:Many join). The configured pop-up windows will show the occupants when I click "Show Related Records". However, I can only search through the source layer, not the related records. Ideally, I could search "Bob Smith" and it would take me to the right polygon, but this is not possible. From my research, I haven't found any work-arounds (no widget or web application template works). I don't want to split every polygon so I can add all the occupants names in, that would take ages. Would a query table help? Does anybody know of any?

[image]

Comment: What's your max number of occupants per plot?

Comment: To split polygon into N parts is no big deal, because it can be easily automated, alternatively you can put multiple polygons on the top of each other

Comment: @FelixIP splitting polygons into N parts is sort of my last resort because if I split the polygons, the wrong people might be in the wrong spot, whereas I know everyone is encompassed by the lot now. How could I automate overlaying 'N' polygons?

Comment: @ShaunO anywhere from 1-20, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @FelixIP now that I think of it, neither of those options will work. They are related based on a common ID, and if I just copied enough polygons so it was a 1:1 join, then my there would be multiples of that ID and would make for a faulty join.

Comment: Never mind everyone, I ended up making a query table and it suited my purposes! Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Would love it if you could explain your solution with screenshots in a new answer.  I was hoping to answer this Q on how you can search related records.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind stacking the polygons (making a duplicate for each name in the plot) you can give this python code a whirl (note:depending on the number of names it could take a long time to process):

```
import arcpy

#make a scrap gdb for merge files
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\somejunk.gdb"

# Make a list of the deceased with a cursor
dTable = r"C:\some.gdb\table"
plotFC = r"C:\some.gdb\plots"

dList = []
idList = []

# Add a name field to the plot feature class

arcpy.AddField_management(plotFC, "Name",TEXT)

#make a list of the deceased and a corres[ponding list with matching plot IDs that your'e using for the current relate

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dTable, ["dTable_ID", "Name"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        idList.append[0]
        dList.appaend[1]
    del row

# Make a zipped list to get the name and IDs as a tuple
DiDlist = zip(idList,dLsit)

#loop through list of deceased, give the current record name to the plot and make a separate feature class
for i in DiDlist:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(plotFC, ["plotfc_ID", "Name"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] = i[0]:
                row[1] = i[1]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                arcpy.FeatureClasstoFeatureClass_conversion(plots, r"C:\somejunk.gdb", "Grave_" + i +"_"+ row[1])
        del row

#make a list to use as the inmput for a merge

mergeList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#merge duplicate plot features
arcpy.Merge_management(mergeList, "All_graves")
```

It will need tweaking to be compatible with your data but you should be able to get the gist from this. You can take it a step further and make an x and y field to calculate the polygons' centroids using the calculate geometry tool, convert the x, ys to points, and then randomize each point within the plot for a density visual or if you don't want your features stacked on top of one another. The python op should give you enough to publish and when you do a name search it should take you to the plot and show you the name.